# Set visibility of view GONE after animation ends

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to set visibility of a view to `GONE` after set its alpha to zero :

```
        view.animate()
            .alpha(0.0f)
            .setDuration(500)
            .setListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                        view.visibility= GONE
                    }
                })
```

But animation shows twice. In the other words, my view shows and hides again after calling `view.visibility= GONE`.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are setting its visibility elsewhere then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My mistake was adding `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` in the root of layout. It animates my view again!

Comment: Just to elaborate on the answer here as I ran into this same problem. Using animateLayoutChanges in combination with the animation onAnimationEnd toggling the View visibility results in two animations running. The code runs once to set alpha to zero and the view disappears a first time. Then when the view is set to GONE in the onAnimationEnd code, a second animation runs from the layout's animateLayoutChanges setting that resets the alpha to 1 and fades out the view for a second time.

Comment: I've been trying for 3 hours to solve this and thanks to you I succeeded, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are using this view animation there is a method which is withEndAction which takes a runnable and with lambda it looks something like this :

```
 view.animate()
        .alpha(0.0f)
        .setDuration(500).withEndAction{
           view.alpha = 0.0f
           view.visibility= GONE 
           }
```

Try this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but problem still exists.

Comment: Ok try setting alpha of the view to 0 in the end action method : 
view.alpha = 0  view.visibility = GONE